# Extract dictionary values from nested keys, leaving main key, then turn into list

Tags: python

```
a = {
    1: {'abc': 50, 'def': 33, 'xyz': 40},
    2: {'abc': 30, 'def': 22, 'xyz': 45},
    3: {'abc': 15, 'def': 11, 'xyz': 50}
}
```

I would like to iterate through this nested dictionary, remove the sub keys (or extract the subkey values), but keep the main keys. the second step would be to turn the dictionary into a list of lists:

```
b = [
    [1, 50, 33, 40],
    [2, 30, 22, 45],
    [3, 15, 11, 50]
]
```

I looked through the myriad of posts here talking about extracting keys and values but cannot find a close enough example to fit to what I need (still new at this): So far, I have this:

```
for key in a.keys():
    if type(a[key]) == dict:
       a[key] = a[key].popitem()[1]
```

which gives this - the value of the third sub key in each key: It's a start, but not complete or what I want

```
{1: 40, 2: 45, 3: 50}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension over [`a.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), use [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) to get the values, and then you can use unpacking (`*`) to get the desired lists.

```
>>> [[k, *v.values()] for k,v in a.items()]
[[1, 50, 33, 40], [2, 30, 22, 45], [3, 15, 11, 50]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be not the most elegant solution, but it does what you exactly want:

```
a = {
    1: {'abc': 50, 'def': 33, 'xyz': 40},
    2: {'abc': 30, 'def': 22, 'xyz': 45},
    3: {'abc': 15, 'def': 11, 'xyz': 50}
}

b = []
for key1, dict2 in a.items():
    c = [key1]
    c.extend(dict2.values())
    b.append(c)

print(b)
```